# How to treat unlinks for computation in the Space Syntax toolkit?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, syntax, streets

Since I cannot find documentation about unlinks for Space Syntax analysis, can unlinks (bridges/ tunnels) be treated just like regular portions of the urban grid? Meaning I can join them to be polylines and then connect them to regular centrelines for a segment map?
Currently, this is how I tackled such a crossing (unlinks are in blue, the regular street segments in red):

[image: Unlinks and regular centrelines]

The regular grid consists out of polylines that are split at intersections.
[image]

This is also how I approached unlinks, but is it correct like this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the answer here: https://github.com/SpaceGroupUCL/qgisSpaceSyntaxToolkit/issues/193

See: [image]